# Combing an Observable result with an existing RxJS Subject without subscribe

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have an existing rxjs Subject.  What I'd like to be able to do is call another Observable and have the results of that observable be 'nexted' into the Subject.  If possible I'd like to be able to get value of the child Observable without calling subscribe on it.

Unfortunately Subscribe.next() requires a value.  Using switchMap directly on the subject also does not work (the switchMap and child call never fires).

```
// init subject in class definition
mySubject$ = new Subject();

// call api and observable
callApi(options) {
   // get an observable from the api call
   const apiResults$ = getApiResults(options);

   // this works but requires an subscribe
   apiResults$.subscribe(results => this.mySubject$.next(results));

   // how to combine the results into the Subject without 
   // the subscribe method (above)
   mySubject$.next(????);
}
```

Comment: You have to subscribe, how else are you going to know when the api observable emits a value? You can use apiResults$.subscribe(this.mySubject$); as a subject is both an observer and an observable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have sort of event observable to listen to api calls, there's a better approach.

You should return api call observable with a `tap` side effect that trigger the subject to emit the result.

```
mySubject$ = new Subject();

callApi(options) {
   return getApiResults(options).pipe(tap(res=>mySubject$.next(res)));

}
```

Comment: `rest` is not defined.  Did you mean `.next(res)`?

Comment: Thanks, let me try that out